# Node.js returning Syntax error: Unexpected identifier

Tags: node.js

I installed Node.js 19.6.0. Now, if I open the Node.js window and type in "git clone [https://github.com/openai/openai-quickstart-node.git"](https://github.com/openai/openai-quickstart-node.git%22) to download the repository i get the error **Unexpected identifier 'clone'**. I am completely new to Node.js and dont understand the reason. Could you help me out?

> git clone https://github.com/openai/openai-quickstart-node.git
> ^^^^^
>
> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'clone'

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfmrJ.png)

best regards
Robert

Opende Node.js and tried to trigger a command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake here is that you're trying to use `git clone` inside of the Node.js interpreter, which is something different than the command line. To clone a repository, you'll need to use the command line on your machine with [Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Installing-Git) installed.